# MySQL get parent/child categories in order

Tags: mysql, multi-level

My question is pretty simple, but I don't know about the answer to it...

I have a table with the following fields and values:

Categories

```
ID | PARENT_ID | NAME
---------------------
 1 |     0     | Cat1
 2 |     0     | Cat2
 3 |     1     | Cat3
 4 |     1     | Cat4
 5 |     3     | Cat5
 6 |     2     | Cat6
 7 |     0     | Cat7
.....
```

Basically, I need to get the data using MySQL only - sorted by Parent_id. Also, for each Name, I need to add '-' sign depending on the level.
In the end it should look like this:

```
ID | PARENT_ID | NAME
---------------------
 1 |     0     | Cat1
 3 |     1     | -Cat3
 5 |     3     | --Cat5
 4 |     1     | -Cat4
 2 |     0     | Cat2
 6 |     2     | -Cat6
 7 |     0     | Cat7
```

I don't know how to start building such a query - I was thinking to order by parent_id, but it will not work.

Is there a function or a method that I could use to achieve this? Any hints will by much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this site: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ as a starting point. You are using the adjacency technique.

Comment: @ AgRizzo - place this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Its not really an answer (no SQL code) - its more of a redirect :) If you develop a solution, you should answer it yourself.

Comment: @ AgRizzo - true, but it solved (or helped a lot) my problem. You have to be rewarded with the answer. I will put the solution directly to the question.

Answer (score 0):

-- not really sure why, or what it could mean, but I think this will do what you are asking:

```
select ID,PARENT_ID,concat(substring('---------------',1,NAME),NAME) as NAME
from table
order by PARENT_ID
```

- note that if there are more than 15 'levels' (or PARENT_ID > 15), you'll need to add more '-'.

Comment: I think you didn't understood my problem. I need to order them based on PARENT_IDs - think of displaying a select box with a list of categories and subcategories...

Comment: just added an order by PARENT_ID to the above.

Comment: If you order by PARENT_ID - will you get my results needed? Check again, as the rows are not ordered like this. The final order is given by the level on which category resides in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using REPEAT SQL function. 
By which you can do 
    Select contact ( REPEAT( '-', parent_id), name) from table order by parent_id;